# Problem with looping a video in Flash

Tags: javascript, html, flash, actionscript

I am trying to loop a video and i am having some issues with this in flash. You can view the video here: http://www.healthcarepros.net/travel.html

Here the specific code for the flash video:

```
<script language="javascript">
if (AC_FL_RunContent == 0) {
    alert("This page requires AC_RunActiveContent.js.");
} else {
    AC_FL_RunContent(
        'codebase', 'http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0',
        'width', '330',
        'height', '245',
        'src', 'healthcare-video',
        'quality', 'high',
        'pluginspage', 'http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer',
        'align', 'middle',
        'play', 'true',
        'loop', 'true',
        'scale', 'showall',
        'wmode', 'window',
        'devicefont', 'false',
        'id', 'healthcare-video',
        'bgcolor', '#ffffff',
        'name', 'healthcare-video',
        'menu', 'true',
        'allowFullScreen', 'false',
        'allowScriptAccess','sameDomain',
        'movie', 'healthcare-video',
        'salign', ''
        ); //end AC code
}
</script>
<noscript>
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0" width="330" height="245" id="healthcare-video" align="middle">
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" />
<param name="loop" value="true" />
<param name="play" value="true" />
<param name="movie" value="healthcare-video.swf" /><param name="quality" value="high" /><param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />    <embed src="healthcare-video.swf" play="true" flashvars="autoplay=true&play=true" quality="high" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="330" height="245" name="healthcare-video" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" allowFullScreen="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
</object>
```

Additionally, i have added in the parameter code that calls the loop function but for some reason it still doesnt seem to work, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The param "loop" refers not to the FLV player, but to the entire SWF, which in this case only has 1 frame so the setting is irrelevant.

The place to set a "loop" option would be in the flashvars string. If you are using the default flash playback component, then IIRC the following should work:

```
flashvars="autoplay=true&play=true&autorewind=true"
```